# Customers multiple email addresses

Tags: customer, email, sales-order

I've been searching high and low but I can't seem to find any information on this. My client would like the ability of multiple email addresses to a customer, so that all sales emails would be sent out to a possible 2+ email addresses.

I know about customer fields, its  the email side I"m a bit wary of.

Has any one got experience with this or have any suggestion on how to approach this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say that the customer fields part you know.
This is a good start.
You should create an other customer attribute called 'secondary_email'. Make it mandatory if needed.

After that you have to change all the methods that send e-mails to customers and make them send and e-mail to the second address also.
Let's take for example `Mage_Sales_Model_Order::sendNewOrderEmail()`.

There is this line that sets the e-mail address and name for the customer to the e-mail.

```
$emailInfo->addTo($this->getCustomerEmail(), $customerName);
```

You need after that this:

```
if ($this->getCustomer() && $this->getCustomer()->getSecondaryEmail()) {
    $emailInfo->addTo($this->getCustomer()->getSecondaryEmail(), $customerName);
}
```

Comment: Perfect, a lot simpler then I thought it would be. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

a simple method is just to explode your email field to an array and use the array in addTo

```
$tab_email_origin = explode(",", $origin['email']);

$mail->setFrom(self::SUPER_EMAIL, 'PMC Tire Inc.')
                 ->addTo($tab_email_origin, $origin['name'])
                 ->setSubject($subject)
                 ->setBodyText('Attached to this email is the shipment\'s packing slip.');
```

so this method suppose that your email address in the database can have multiple emails separated with comma.

Answer (score 0):

One Approach is that like you can create one customer Attribute like another "Email" Address.

then you have to override the order Module. when you place an order then you have to fetch this email id of that customer and add that email id to the CC.

This is simple but tricky solutions.